# Fresh Xampp installation gives losanges with question mark characters everywhere

Tags: xampp

Just installed a new computer with ubuntu 14.04, and adding  xampp gives strange characters everywhere ... only in the xampp pages. What happens ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens ?

This is an issue with the default Apache character set. You have to change it to **iso-8859-1**

**This how it looks first:**

[image]

**Then you have to add at the end of the `php.ini` file** `default_charset = "iso-8859-1"`

[image]

[image]

Restart Apache (Stop/Start)

It will get fix

[image]

Comment: Let me add the linux ubuntu way of doing : sudo gedit ./opt/lampp/etc/php.ini to edit the init file and sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start to start apache. It works !